# Internal Tempo link is not getting populated to get the traces in Loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, tempo

I have integrated Grafana Loki and Tempo in EKS cluster. I am able to query the services from loki, but the internal tracing URL for Tempo is not getting populated in Loki. I have flunetbit deployed which is pushing the logs to loki.

I am accesing Grafana with Ingress controler.  Have deployed otel-collector in order to get the tracing information from the cluster. Can someone please suggest on this , its been days since i am stuck in this issue.!

```
datasources:
 datasources.yaml:
   apiVersion: 1
   datasources:
     - name: Tempo
       type: tempo
       access: browser
       orgId: 1
       uid: tempo
       url: http://tempo:3100
       isDefault: true
       editable: true
     - name: Loki
       type: loki
       access: browser
       orgId: 1
       uid: loki
       url: http://loki:3100
       isDefault: false
       editable: true
       jsonData:
         derivedFields:
           - datasourceName: Tempo
             matcherRegex: "traceID=(\\w+)"
             name: TraceID
             url: "$${__value.raw}"
             datasourceUid: tempo

env:
 JAEGER_AGENT_PORT: 6831

adminUser: admin
adminPassword: password

service:
 type: ClusterIP
```

```
tempo:
 extraArgs:
   "distributor.log-received-traces": true
 receivers:
   zipkin:
   otlp:
     protocols:
       http:
       grpc:
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: otel-collector-conf
 namespace: monitoring-loki
 labels:
   app: opentelemetry
   component: otel-collector-conf
data:
 otel-collector-config: |
   receivers:
     zipkin:
       endpoint: 0.0.0.0:9411
   exporters:
     otlp:
       endpoint: tempo.tracing.svc.cluster.local:55680
       insecure: true
   service:
     pipelines:
       traces:
         receivers: [zipkin]
         exporters: [otlp]
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: monitoring-loki
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry
    component: otel-collector
spec:
  ports:
  - name: otlp # Default endpoint for OpenTelemetry receiver.
    port: 55680
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 55680
  - name: jaeger-grpc # Default endpoint for Jaeger gRPC receiver
    port: 14250
  - name: jaeger-thrift-http # Default endpoint for Jaeger HTTP receiver.
    port: 14268
  - name: zipkin # Default endpoint for Zipkin receiver.
    port: 9411
  - name: metrics # Default endpoint for querying metrics.
    port: 8888
  - name: prometheus # prometheus exporter
    port: 8889

  selector:
    component: otel-collector
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
  namespace: monitoring-loki
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry
    component: otel-collector
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: opentelemetry
      component: otel-collector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: opentelemetry
        component: otel-collector
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
          - "/otelcontribcol"
          - "--config=/conf/otel-collector-config.yaml"
#           Memory Ballast size should be max 1/3 to 1/2 of memory.
          - "--mem-ballast-size-mib=683"
          - "--log-level=DEBUG"
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.29.0
        name: otel-collector
        ports:
        - containerPort: 55679 # Default endpoint for ZPages.
        - containerPort: 55680 # Default endpoint for OpenTelemetry receiver.
        - containerPort: 14250 # Default endpoint for Jaeger HTTP receiver.
        - containerPort: 14268 # Default endpoint for Jaeger HTTP receiver.
        - containerPort: 9411 # Default endpoint for Zipkin receiver.
        - containerPort: 8888  # Default endpoint for querying metrics.
        - containerPort: 8889  # prometheus exporter       
        volumeMounts:
        - name: otel-collector-config-vol
          mountPath: /conf
        # livenessProbe:
        #   httpGet:
        #     path: /
        #     port: 13133 # Health Check extension default port.
        # readinessProbe:
        #   httpGet:
        #     path: /
        #     port: 13133 # Health Check extension default port.
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            name: otel-collector-conf
            items:
              - key: otel-collector-config
                path: otel-collector-config.yaml
          name: otel-collector-config-vol
```

```
fluent-bit:
 enabled: false
promtail:
 enabled: true
prometheus:
 enabled: false
 alertmanager:
   persistentVolume:
     enabled: true
 server:
   persistentVolume:
     enabled: false
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-config
  namespace: monitoring-loki
data:
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf

    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Path              /var/log/*.log
        Parser            docker
        Tag               kube.*
        Refresh_Interval  5
        Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off            

    [OUTPUT]
        Name              loki
        Match             kube.*
        Host              "loki-svc.monitoring-loki"
        tenant_id         ""
        Port              "3100"
        label_keys        $trace_id
        auto_kubernetes_labels on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something in your Loki datasource:

```
    derivedFields:
      - datasourceUid: tempo
        matcherRegex: 'traceID=(\\w+)'
        name: TraceID
        url: $${__value.raw}
        urlDisplayLabel: Find this trace in Tempo
```

Comment: you mean i need add "urlDisplayLabel: Find this trace in Tempo"

Comment: @HarshVardhan not just that, for example how do you know that `datasourceName` is supported there (chatgpt?)? Just copy&paste my suggested config and test it with latest stable Grafana version.

Comment: It worked i am getting that. Now i am not able to get the traces in tempo. " Getting error trace not found in Tempo, 404 message body not found! Can you please help on this! I am stuck in this issue from couple days!